# Synology OpenVPN User cannot access internet

Tags: port, firewall, synology, nas

I just recently set up a OpenVPN Server on my NAS. I was able to connect to it and access local devices over it (like the NAS and router) but *not* the internet. I tried some different things and I found out that it was because of the firewall of my Synology NAS (if I disable the firewall I can access the internet). However, I have already opened the VPN Server Port in the NAS' firewall and also my routers firewall (Port 1194).

I guess I now have to add a new rule specifically for the VPN users?

If so, what's the most secure way to do that?

What I came up with is **allowing IPs in the range of what the VPN users should have access to all ports, but only outwards** (in the NAS firewall), but I'm not sure if this really is secure, so what's the optimal way to solve this issue?

Thank you for your help!

What I already tried:

- turn off NAS firewall (works, but not secure)
- add new firewall rule to allow outward access of all ports to VPN-user-ips (not sure if this is secure or the way to go)
- open the VPN Server Port (if this *wouldn't* work, I would not have been able to connect to the VPN in the first place I think)